# How to get all tags' descriptions from the Stack Exchange API directly?

Tags: support, api-v2.2, tags

I know I can get one tag description by request such as "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/tag_name/wikis?site=dba".

But if I use it more than hundreds of times, I will get a throttle_violation error:

> {"error_id":502,"error_message":"too many requests from this IP, more requests available in 76620 seconds","error_name":"throttle_violation"}

There is a method related to this problem: [How to get tags using the API?](https://stackapps.com/questions/2608/how-to-get-tags-using-the-api)

such as "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/tag_name1;tag_name2/wikis?site=dba".

But there are too many tags in one site, the method of using semicolon splitting and merging tags seems to be limited to 20.

Is there any way to get all tags' description using the API?

Comment: I have no access_token, does it cause the throttle_violation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're already doing the right thing by [batching](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/vectors) the requests to minimize the number of API calls (just group them in groups of 30 or so) but you're still limited to 300 requests per day, as per [How API Keys Work (FAQ)](https://stackapps.com/q/67/34061). You have to [register your application](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) (you don't even need to authenticate your user) to get a request key for it, and using that will give you an increased quota of 10,000.